# Speed up WooCommerce Imports

Tags: mysql, import, woocommerce

I've just imported about 7,000 products to my database and there is thousands more to come. I have a VPS and during the import it only shows me using about 25% of the resources. When I first started importing they got inserted about 1 every 15 seconds or so, now it's taking 3 or more minutes per product. Is there a way to speed up the MySQL queries?

Comment: Could you share such csv file please, so I can try to play with it and find out where it is slow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. The plugin has to check every product imported against pre-existing ones. Therefore, the more you add the slower its going to get. If you have 10k+ porducts, you might want to consider a CMS designed for shops, as opposed to WP.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't totally given up on WooCommerce yet, check out WP All Import - http://www.wpallimport.com/

It allows you to import large files in chunks for way faster imports. I use it to manage a WooCommerce store with over 15,000 products.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Images

The slowest thing is usually remote image fetching. I don't know what field structure you're importing but if there are images, the import tool (like WebToffee) has to check remote URLs to download the images themselves, and one product can contain many so this will take a while. So whenever possible, get rid of any column with image links.

#### 2. Number of columns

If you're just updating existing rows, limit the input to columns that have possibly changed. Like prices, inventory, etc, but not the product specs & descriptions.

#### 3. Concurrent access

If anyone is accessing the site at the moment of import, reads and writes will wait for each other so it will be a lot slower. If possible, use a cron job for imports and choose a time window where your traffic is low.